# Locking tables causes savepoint issues with django

Tags: mysql, django, mariadb, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to build a Directed-Acyclical-Graph (DAG) in a MariaDB database within a Django application. Because this is acyclical, I need to verify that any added elements (vertexes/edges) do not create cycles within the graph.

Many clients will attempt to add elements concurrently throughout the day, however these cycle checks need to be atomic, so I have reasoned that I need to use some lock when adding/updating elements. Django doesnt seem to provide anything like this, so I am trying to use a raw `LOCK TABLES`/`UNLOCK TABLES` query. Here is the code I use to do that...

```
def lock_tables():                                                                    
    cursor = get_connection(DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS).cursor()                            

    tables = [                                                                    
        'vertex',                                                  
        'edge'                                                                                             
    ]                                                                             

    lock_query = ', '.join(                                                
        "{} {}".format(table, 'WRITE') for table in tables                        
    )                                                                             

    query = 'LOCK TABLES {}'.format(lock_query)                            
    cursor.execute(query)                                                         


def unlock_tables():                                                                  
    cursor = get_connection(DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS).cursor()                            
    cursor.execute('UNLOCK TABLES')
```

And then in my mode's `save` method...

```
@transaction.atomic()
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    print("---INSIDE MODEL SAVE")

    try:
        print("---LOCKING TABLES")
        lock_tables()
        print("---LOCKED TABLES")

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        # TODO: Add Cycle check here
    except Exception as ex:
        print("---EXCEPTION THROWN INSIDE SAVE: {}".format(ex))
        raise
    finally:
        print("---UNLOCKING TABLES")
        unlock_tables()
        print("---UNLOCKED TABLES")
```

However, something about locking and unlocking these tables is messing with savepoints created using `django.db.transaction.atomic`... At some point when Django tries to exit an `atomic` context, it tries to roll back to a savepoint that it has already released.

Here are some logs where I try to capture the problem, `Executing Query` lines are from `django.db.backends.mysql.base`, `STARTING/EXITING ATOMIC` lines are from `django.db.transactions.atomic` `__enter__`/`__exit__` methods, and notes following `####` are comments I added after the fact to try to explain what I think is going on.

```
---STARTING ATOMIC  #### Atomic context wrapping my serializer's create method
Executing query: 'SAVEPOINT `s139667621889792_x1`' - args: None

---STARTING ATOMIC  #### Atomic context wrapping my model's save method
Executing query: 'SAVEPOINT `s139667621889792_x2`' - args: None

---INSIDE MODEL SAVE
---LOCKING TABLES
Executing query: 'LOCK TABLES vertex WRITE, edge WRITE
---LOCKED TABLES

---STARTING ATOMIC  #### I think Django must wrap some queries in an atomic block, but this doesnt even create a savepoint
Executing query: 'INSERT INTO `edge`...
---EXITING ATOMIC

#### WHERE MY CYCLE CHECK CODE WOULD RUN - not implemented yet

---UNLOCKING TABLES
Executing query: 'UNLOCK TABLES' - args: None
---UNLOCKED TABLES

---EXITING ATOMIC
Executing query: 'RELEASE SAVEPOINT `s139667621889792_x2`' - args: None
Executing query: 'ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT `s139667621889792_x2`' - args: None   ### WHAT I BELIEVE TO BE THE OFFENDING QUERY

---EXITING ATOMIC
Executing query: 'ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT `s139667621889792_x1`' - args: None

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File ".../site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 72, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File ".../site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File ".../site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File ".../site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File ".../site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 727, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File ".../site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1066, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File ".../site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 683, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File ".../site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File ".../site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1305, 'SAVEPOINT s139667621889792_x2 does not exist')
```

As shown above, django tries to roll back to a savepoint that it has already released. If I remove the call to lock/unlock tables, this code works perfectly, however I can no longer guarantee my cycle checks are atomic.

Has anyone run into this issue before, or have any tips on how to dig deeper into the cause?

**EDIT:** The more I read into this, the more I think my desired behavior is not possible. Per the [MySQL docs on locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html#lock-tables-and-transactions), It seems that transactions are committed when you get a lock on a table. This breaks my use case, as I want a transaction to be rolled back if my cycle check fails.

Answer (score 1):

Any anti-cycle algorithm depends on the table not changing while the check is being performed.  Correct?  How long does it take to perform a cycle check?  How many checks do you need per day?

Assuming you have enough time to do all that work, then consider this:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('cycle_check');  -- (you may want timeout)
BEGIN;
INSERT new item in graph
perform cycle check
if ... COMMIT else ROLLBACK
SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('cycle_check');
```

Note that this locking mechanism does not have the same characteristics that lead `LOCK TABLES` to be useless.

To prevent reads during cycle checks, you also need:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('cycle_check');
SELECT ...;
SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('cycle_check');
```

(Side note:  It is extremely rare for `GET_LOCK` to be the 'right' way to do locking.  Please do not extend this to arbitrary other situations.)

Comment: I didn't know locks could also be independent of tables! That may be useful... will report back. Cycle checks should block changes AND reads (don't want someone to read a new vertex/edge while it is being checked)

Comment: @wKavey - I guess you would need GET/RELEASE around `SELECTs`, too.  This is a simple-minded implementation, unlike most db locks that would allow multiple simultaneous readers.  I added a note about reading.  (I don't see a way to allow simultaneous `SELECTs` _and_ avoid cycle checks.)

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm building a dependency management system, so I'm going to need to perform this check on every addition (to prevent a bad dependency from being added), which will possibly have a lot of overhead. I may need to re-evaluate my approach, because manually wrapping selects that Django performs isnt the simplest thing to do.